# Is there any way to get apk file directly from google play store?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I need to download apk file from google play store directly using package name in java.

There are multiple online tools which do something similar..

http://www.apksmart.com/

https://apkpure.com/region-free-apk-download

https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/

http://apkleecher.com/

http://apk-downloaders.com/

If we provide a Package name or Google Play URL, it will return the apk download link.

I am tried with the link in java,

```
String url = https://apkpure.com/google-play-store/com.aws.android/download?from=details
```

My code,

```
void downloadFromUrl(URL url, String localFilename) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();//connect
            urlConn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
            is = urlConn.getInputStream();               //get connection inputstream
            fos = new FileOutputStream(localFilename);   //open outputstream to local file

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];              //declare 4KB buffer
            int len;

            //while we have availble data, continue downloading and storing to local file
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the above code returns the html page. But I need to store the downloaded apk file. How to get work this??

Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: Why cannot you get the apk directly from google?

Comment: I can get apk in a browser console but I need to get programmatically... How to get apk using java code??